# Jmeter's cookies don't have the same data as in web browser

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I'm trying to correlate value in variable named `deviceId`. However I can't find such thing in previous responses to extract. But I found that some requests have this value in Request Headers cookies under variable named `sn-chatbot-deviceId`

[image]

Unfortunately when I ran the test and inspect the same request, I saw that my Jmeter's cookies don't have this variable `sn-chatbot-deviceId` in them. According to Console web browser it should be in Request Header, but there I don't have cookies

[image]

In Request Body I have cookies, but there isn't variable `sn-chatbot-deviceId`

[image]

I would appreciate it If anyone tell me why I don't have this variable in my JMeter cookies

Answer (score 0):

JMeter does check cookies for validity and verifies:

- domain
- expiration
- path
- etc.

and in case of any mismatch with the specification - JMeter doesn't store the cookie into HTTP Cookie Manager

Browsers are less restrictive and try to parse invalid HTML, send cookies no matter of their validity, etc. so you can configure JMeter to remove the restrictions by:

- adding the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

  ```
  CookieManager.check.cookies=false
  ```
- choosing the less restrictive implementation like `netscape`

  [image]

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)

If this doesn't help (which I doubt) you should still be able to extract the missing cookie from the [Set-Cookie response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) and add it to the HTTP Cookie Manager manually

Comment: Hi Dmitri,
Thank you for your help. Unfortunately after adding this line to `CookieManager.check.cookies=false` to user.properties and selecting `netscape` option I still have the same cookies.